# TextEditController onchange not working properly in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

When I input something then change, another calculation is working well, but `TextEditController` field clear at a time.

My source code details

```
      TextEditingController qtnCtnController = TextEditingController();
  TextField(
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    controller: qtnCtnController,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    labelText: 'Qty(Ctn)',
    hintText: '0',
    labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
    autofocus: true,
    onChanged: (qtnNumber) {

            print("ontestts:"+qtnNumber);
            if(qtnNumber.isEmpty)
            {
              print("ontestts:if"+qtnNumber);
            }
            else {                                
                print("ontestts:else:qtnNumber:last:"+qtnNumber);
                  setState(() {  
                            int multiplication = qtnNumber * 4;                        
                    qtnCtnController.text = "asfsadfasdf";
                    print("ontestts:else:qtnNumber:last:lasteee:"+qtnNumber);
                  });

               }
    }                                  
);
```

When I input 5 then I calculate 5*4 = 20, work fine,
but `TextEditController` field 0.
But I want to show `TextEditController` field 5.

How to possible keep show in input type value.

Comment: Your textfiled clears after calculation?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this reference hope it will work for you thanks

https://www.ravsam.in/blog/build-a-tip-calculator-app-in-flutter/